# How do I remove the profile photo from a Yahoo! account?

Tags: yahoo-account

I have tried following steps from a lot of articles online, but they all seem to be outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo have changed things so nobody can change/edit/remove their profile pic or nickname. We have been told that we will be able to in the future, so sit and wait.

Comment: Can you add a reference to support your answer?